# Is there a way to get the ID of the textbox created by ZeppelinContext's z.input

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a spark based note in Zeppelin, where by using Javascript I want to modify the text in a text box created through Zeppelin's `z.input`. Is this even possible? I mean, can I get the ID of such a texbox so that I can modify its value through Javascript's HTML DOM functions.